# Bootstrap Datetimepicker and X-editable - parse error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, x-editable, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I was trying to find solution but I did not succeed.

I am trying to run X-editable with 'datetime' type to give user datetimepicker.
Bootstrap DateTimePicker is working well with other elements on the same page so it is not issue with DTP.

Despite of choosing way of 'data-*' or pushing everything thru JS, I always get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseFormat' of undefineda.extend.initPicker 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:7b 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:7a.fn.editableutils.createInput 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:5b.init 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:5b 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:5(anonymous function) 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:5n.extend.each 
@ jquery.js:374n.fn.n.each 
@ jquery.js:139a.fn.editable 
@ bootstrap-editable.min.js:5(anonymous function) 
@ panel:1016j 
@ jquery.js:3099k.fireWith 
@ jquery.js:3211n.extend.ready 
@ jquery.js:3417I @ jquery.js:3433
```

When I change from *min* to normal JS I tracked it to:

```
this.parsedFormat = this.dpg.parseFormat(this.options.format, this.options.formatType);
```

I have no idea how to solve it.
I even copied whole example from x-editable docs, as I was afraid it is some misspelling but it is not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in x-editable. Looking at their source code, the setup of the datetimepicker has

```
//store DPglobal
this.dpg = $.fn.datetimepicker.DPGlobal; 

//store parsed formats
this.parsedFormat = this.dpg.parseFormat(this.options.format, this.options.formatType);
```

but the datetimepicker plugin doesn't actually have a DPGlobal property so `this.dpg` is undefined.

However, the datepicker setup has similar code that does work

```
//store DPglobal
this.dpg = $.fn.bdatepicker.DPGlobal; 

//store parsed formats
this.parsedFormat = this.dpg.parseFormat(this.options.format);
```

because DPGlobal is actually set within the datepicker plugin source

The setup of the datetimepicker should be using `$.fn.bdatepicker.DPGlobal` instead of `$.fn.datetimepicker.DPGlobal`

Comment: Did anyone ever get a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: In `bootstrap-editable.js`, look for `this.dpg = $.fn.datetimepicker.DPGlobal;` and change it to `this.dpg = $.fn.bdatepicker.DPGlobal;`